# Проблемы с CORS на javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, url, xmlhttprequest, cors

Есть следующий код, написан ниже (тестовый запрос на Google делал:)). Проблема в том, что переодически (довольно редко, но все же) вылетают ошибки связанные с доступом CORS, мол извините нет доступа заголовок запроса не содержит CORS привилегий. Помогите разобраться, может нужно в запросах как-то указывать заголовки CORS? Напишите пожалуйста что знаете по данной теме

```
let url = new URL('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml')
    const xml = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
    xml.open("GET", url, false)
    xml.send(null);
    alert(xml.responseText)
```

Comment: сервер должен проставлять заголовок access-control-allow-origin, разрешая таким образом запросы с других доменов

Comment: если ошибка периодическая, возможно в этот момент запрос возвращает ошибку, а в ней не указаны заголовки CORS.